# Symfony3 Edit Entity : Error Missing value for primary key

Tags: doctrine, entity, primary-key, symfony, composite-key

I try to create a tree structure for a catalog of products.
A catalog can have multiple levels and levels can contain multiple products.

I manage to save my structure in database but when I want to edit it, I have this error :

```
Error : Missing value for primary key catalogCode on AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel
at OutOfBoundsException ::missingPrimaryKeyValue ('AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel', 'catalogCode')
in vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory.php at line 125
```

when I do this in my CatalogController :

```
$form = $this->createForm(CatalogTreeType::class, $catalog);
```

But, just before that line, I verify if I get my levels correctly and it's looking like that's the case :

```
// Create an ArrayCollection of the current levels
$originalLevels = new ArrayCollection();
foreach ($catalog->getLevels() as $level) {
   var_dump($level->getCatalogCode());
   $originalLevels->add($level);
}

// returns
AppBundle\Controller\CatalogController.php:337:string 'TT-FTEST' (length=8)

AppBundle\Controller\CatalogController.php:337:string 'TT-FTEST' (length=8)
```

`CatalogLevel` entity has a composite key : levelId + catalogCode.

Considering the primary key `catalogCode` **isn't empty**, I don't understand this error...

**Catalog Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="catalogue")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CatalogRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="code", message="Catalog code already exists")
 */
class Catalog
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Catalogue_Code", type="string", length=15)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=15, maxMessage="The code is too long ({{ limit }} characters max)")
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CatalogLevel", mappedBy="catalog", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $levels;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->levels = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get levels
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getLevels()
    {
      return $this->levels;
    }

    /**
     * Add level
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel $level
     *
     * @return Catalog
     */
    public function addLevel(\AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel $level)
    {
        $level->setCatalogCode($this->getCode());
        $level->setCatalog($this);

        if (!$this->getLevels()->contains($level)) {
            $this->levels->add($level);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove level
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel $level
     */
   public function removeLevel(\AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevel $level)
    {
        $this->levels->removeElement($level);
    }
}
```

**CatalogLevel Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="catalogue_niveau")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevelRepository")
 */
class CatalogLevel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Niveau_ID", type="string", length=15)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Catalogue_Code", type="string", length=15)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $catalogCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Catalog", inversedBy="levels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Catalogue_Code", referencedColumnName="Catalogue_Code")
     */
    private $catalog;

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param string $id
     *
     * @return CatalogLevel
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set catalogCode
     *
     * @param string $catalogCode
     *
     * @return CatalogLevel
     */
    public function setCatalogCode($catalogCode)
    {
        $this->catalogCode = $catalogCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get catalogCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCatalogCode()
    {
        return $this->catalogCode;
    }
}
```

I would like to remind you that this error occured on the editAction (it works very well on the addAction) when I display the pre-filled form.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you haven't autoincrement id in entity CatalogLevel. Try add to id this code:

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't use an auto increment id for CatalogLevel because I create my tree with jquery and I fix ids with form data after submit. For example, level id is something like this : item-1, item-2, item-xx.

The save in database works well. I have all my level data in my "catalogue_niveau" table. Moreover, my error occured on AbstractProxyFactory class and not directly on the Entity CatalogLevel.

Comment: Ok, so I do not know what could be causing but there is an easier way to do it. You can use [doctrine tree extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#including-extension). All magic in one table.

Comment: I don't know that, thank you ! I'll see if it corresponds to my structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in the way you've created you Entities. You should use auto generate strategy. Also the "@ORM\Id" annotation is the unique identifier.

Also, your "JoinColumn" is incorrect. You need to refer back to the "Catalog" Entity, and it's id (identifier). There is no need for 2 "@ORM\Id" entries in the class CatalogLevel.

So make these changes:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="catalog")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CatalogRepository")
 */
class Catalog
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="cat_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $cat_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CatalogLevel", mappedBy="catalog", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $levels;
     ...


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="catalog_level")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CatalogLevelRepository")
 */
class CatalogLevel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="cat_level_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $cat_level_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Catalog", inversedBy="levels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="local_cat_id", referencedColumnName="cat_id")
     */
    private $catalog;
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't use an auto increment id for Catalog and CatalogLevel. The user can enter a code for a catalog and this code is used as the primary key.
In order to have unique identifier for levels, I use a composite key composed with catalog code and level id that I get after submit my form (I construct a drag and drop tree in jquery and ids are generated in js).
The save in database works well. I have all my level data in my "catalogue_niveau" table. Moreover, my error occured on AbstractProxyFactory class and not directly on the Entity CatalogLevel.

Comment: I found a way on internet to avoid this error : remove @ORM\Id for $catalogCode property in entity CatalogLevel.

The edit form is displaying and it is pre-filled with levels data. But I don't think this is a viable solution...